# UILabel followed by UIButton

Tags: swift

How can I add a `UIButton` at the end of `UILabel`, just like a *Read More*, using Swift3?

I have already created a `UILabel` and `UIButton` using storyboard.

I do not want to use any pod extension.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue? The layout?

Answer (score 0):

I see only two ways of doing that.

**1.** If you have a single-line `UILabel` then you can place your button right next to it using `AutoLayout`.

**2.** If your label has or may have multiple lines, then I'd suggest you use a single `UITextView` instead of `UILabel` and `UIButton`. Set up your text view and then add any text you want as a clickable ending using the following method. Just make sure that you've set `textView.isEditable` to `false`.

```
func addReadMore(at textView: UITextView) {
    let originalString = textView.text + " "
    let readMoreLine = "Read more..."
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalString + readMoreLine)
    let range = NSRange(location: originalString.count, length: readMoreLine.count)
    attributedString.addAttribute(.link, value: "readMorePressed", range: range)
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Then you should make your `ViewController` a `UITextView` delegate and implement the following method.

```
public func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    if URL.absoluteString == "readMorePressed" {
        // show more content
    }
    return true
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `UILabel`s can display multiple lines of text. You can set the lines property to 0 and use text that contains newlines.

Comment: @DuncanC Sure. That's why I've said that `AutoLayout` may help only when it has a single line of text. And if you want to place something after the last line of the **multi-line** text, it'll be better to use `UITextView`.